# Variable Won't Define Properly

Tags: vb.net, variables

I'm trying to define an array but in my defining statement it says that the variable is being used before it is assigned a value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSolve.Click
    Dim txtNumber1() As Integer = {Val(Me.txt1Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt2Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt3Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt4Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt5Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt6Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt7Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt8Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt9Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt10Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt11Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt12Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt13Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt14Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt15Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt16Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt17Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt18Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt19Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt20Number1.Text)}
    Dim txtNumber2() As Integer = {Val(Me.txt1Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt2Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt3Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt4Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt5Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt6Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt7Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt8Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt9Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt10Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt11Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt12Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt13Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt14Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt15Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt16Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt17Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt18Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt19Number2.Text), Val(Me.txt20Number2.Text)}
    Dim txtAnswer() As Integer = {Val(Me.txt1Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt2Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt3Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt4Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt5Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt6Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt7Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt8Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt9Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt10Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt11Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt12Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt13Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt14Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt15Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt16Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt17Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt18Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt19Answer.Text), Val(Me.txt20Answer.Text)}
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intRealAnswer() As Integer
    For i = 0 To txtNumber1(i) - 1
        intRealAnswer(i) = txtNumber1(i) - txtNumber2(i)
        If txtAnswer(i) = intRealAnswer(i) Then
            Me.lblAnswer1.Text = "Correct:" & intRealAnswer(i)
        Else
            Me.lblAnswer1.Text = "Incorrect:" & intRealAnswer(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The error is occurring in the line intRealAnswer(i) = txtNumber1(i) - txtNumber2(i) 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have declared `intRealAnswer`:

```
Dim intRealAnswer() As Integer
```

You haven't specified how many items are in the array. You can do this like you have with your other variables if you need to initialise some value. Something like this:

```
Dim intRealAnswer() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 0, ...}
```

Alternatively you can do this to declare an array of 10 items (index 0 to 9):

```
Dim intRealAnswer(9) As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your array or declare its size before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your ints a default value?

```
Dim i As Integer = 0 
Dim intRealAnswer() As Integer = {0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line 
`Dim intRealAnswer() As Integer`
to `Dim intRealAnswer As Integer`
There is no real reason it needs to be an array since you are only storing the current value. Also as note you should get rid of the Val() and use Integer.Parse() and on your form if someone puts 1.5 into a textbox are you checking to see that value is really an integer first? Just something to learn with taking inputs that users who are allowed to enter 1.5 in one textbox and 3.0 in another will be expecting to see a decimal in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I Recomend to use IEnumerable object, like List(Of Interger) witch

```
Dim txtNumbers as New List(Of Integer) From {Val(Me.txt1Number1.Text), Val(Me.txt2Number1.Text), ...}

txtNumbers.Add(Val(Me.txt3Number1.Text))
```

Or even you can "`Add`" one by one or just "`AddRange`". Creative use a "`For Each Item as Control in Me.Controls`" to make list posible.